# I would suggest that the reason for the fault is/was/would be lack of attention

Tags: grammar

Which of the above three options sounds more natural?

If I wanted to distance myself from the statement to a greater extent than implied by "would suggest", should I keep "would be lack of attention"?

Secondly, of the two options is/was, does it make sense to choose "is", even though the error in question occurred a long time ago?

Thanks.

Comment: 'I would suggest ... would be' sounds odd; I'd suggest 'I would suggest ... could/might be' as hedged versions. 'Is' is just about licensed as you're discussing an eternal truth (it happened; the fault is fact) in the here and now. But past simple is surely more idiomatic, unless the present consequences are very real.

Comment: It sounds as if you are tentatively suggesting an explanation for some past event.  I would therefore me inclined to use ‘would have been’.

Comment: Wouldn't it sound clunky to use "would have been" right after "would suggest"? How would your answers change if I put it this way: I would suggest that the most likely reason for the fault was/would have been?

Comment: @Supersup Not so much clunky, I would say, as cautiously distances.  Caution is not zippy.

Comment: So, just to be sure, you won't find it odd to read in an academic paper the following sentence, will you? I would suggest that the most likely reason...would have been lack of space. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: One last thing: is the indefinite article compulsory here, i.e. a lack of space